# Invariant subspace of orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is Euclidean space, $W$ is it's subspace.
$T$ is an orthogonal transformation T: V $\rightarrow$ V
$W$ is $T$ invariant.
**Is W equal to the range of $T(w)$, $w \in W$?**

I thought about it visually:
Orthogonal transformation can be viewed as a (rigid or improper) rotation.
Given a unique vector the result of the transformation will also be unique, so the range of $T(w)$ must be the same size than that of W.
Given that W is $T$ invariant: $T(w) \in W$, $w \in W$, then they must be equal.

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every orthogonal transformation is invertible. This means in particular that it is injective, and then its kernel is zero. Considering $T$ restricted to $W$, you have (by the rank-nullity theorem)
$$\dim\Big(\ker \left(T\mid_W\right)\Big) + \dim\Big(T(W)\Big) = \dim( W ).$$
Since $\ker\left(T\mid_W\right) = \{0\}$, we must have $T(W) = W$.

Comment: One should also add that $V$ is finite-dimensional, which OP seems to forget to include.

Comment: @awllower You're right, but I think the term "Euclidean space" usually means some $\mathbb{R}^n$, as opposed to "Inner product space", which could mean an infinite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: I agree. In any case, thanks for this good answer.

Comment: where was used here the invariance of $W$?

Comment: of course, in T(W) subspace of W. sorry, I´m dumb